# Looping function bash

Tags: bash, function, loops, break

I'm currently learning bash and I'm working on loop function to recall the function if the value is not the expected.

I create a small function

```
#!/bin/bash

find_number(){
  echo "Enter number"
  read number

  if [ ! $number == 1 ]; then
    echo is not 1, enter number again
    find_number
  fi

echo "Got it"
}

find_number
```

If you enter a bad value it restart the function and create a loop but the only problem is that the functions loops itself and finally when it continues it returns the echo as many time as you got it wrong.

Exemple:

```
   Enter number
   5
   is not 1, enter number again
   Enter number
   5
   is not 1, enter number again
   Enter number
   1
   Got it
   Got it
   Got it
```

As you see here I've got the result 3 times.
To resolve this problem I've writtten my code in another way.

```
#!/bin/bash

find_number(){

  echo "Enter number"

  while read number; do
    if [ ! $number == 1 ]; then
      echo is not 1, enter number again
    else
      break
    fi
  done

echo "Got it"
}

find_number
```

My question is...am I doing it the right way by applying this second method or there's another way of doing it ?

thanks for your feedback

Comment: FYI, `==` is not part of POSIX-standardized `test` functionality; the standard string comparison operator is `=`. And always quote your expansions -- `! [ "$number" = 1 ]` is much less prone to surprises; consider what happens if a user enters `23 = 23 -o 5`; you get `[ ! 23 = 23 -o 5 == 1 ]`.

Comment: When you want to check something is not equal to an int in bash, use `if [ $number != 1 ]`. It is more readable as well.

Comment: @Vinny, err, re: "to an int" -- that's string comparison, not numeric comparison. (`=` is string comparison as well; if we're sure the values are in the same base and don't have leading zeroes it doesn't matter so much until we start to do greater or less-than comparisons).

Comment: ...and since this is inaccurately describing recursion as "looping", I'm calling it too-broad -- it's not really a bash question at all; someone could have this exact same misconception, misunderstanding, and associated bug in **any** language with a call stack (and thus which allows reentrant functions).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I meant numeric comparison, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, beside syntax, I understand that the second method is correct?

Comment: @Vinny, ...to perform a numeric comparison, it would be `[ "$number" -ne 1 ]`

Comment: @DavidPeltier, correct, the while loop is the better practice. It's *possible* to write a recursive function that behaves the way you want, but you get various bugs that way (the more times you "loop", the more memory you use, and eventually you run out of call stack).

Comment: Thanks to all for your answers and corrections, I'll take note of all of that, my question has been answered 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using recursion, not loop. Try to use loop in this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

find_number(){
  echo "Enter number"
  read number

  while [ ! "${number}" == "1" ]; do
    echo "is not 1, enter number again"
    read number
  done

  echo "Got it"
}

find_number
```

Comment: `[ ! $number == 1 ]` is buggy. Consider what happens if `number` is an empty string, or `23 = 23 -o 5`. Always quote your expansions, and use POSIX-compliant syntax (`=`, not `==`) so your code works on shells such as ash or dash: `! [ "$number" = 1 ]`

Comment: The quotes are indeed helpful; the curly braces don't make a difference; the `==` vs `=` distinction still makes this code bash-only (as opposed to being able to work on Debian systems with dash).

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to 'loop', when each function finishes, you are still performing the final lines of that function as they complete.

To truly create a loop, you would use your `while; do` structure to perform it properly.

Calling the function itself for recursion can create a bigger overhead if you don't have a solid base (ending) condition.